# Django: set ManyToMany field initially empty in model create form

Tags: django, forms, manytomanyfield

I have following models:

```
class Robject(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(to=Project, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        to=User, null=True, related_name="robjects_in_which_user_is_author")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    create_by = models.ForeignKey(
        to=User, related_name="robjects_created_by_user", null=True)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    modify_by = models.ForeignKey(to=User, null=True)
    name = models.ManyToManyField(
        "Name", related_name="robject_name",
        help_text='The name of robject'
    )


class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    primary = models.BooleanField()
```

I want to create a form where user can create new Robjects. I want this form works the same as Robject create form in admin page. It means I want to have 'plus' button next to 'name' select multiple input, that user can click and create new Name in window popup form. After Name creation popup closes and user can see new Name in select input. My problem is that user shouldn't see any already existing Name objects created during other Robject creation attempts. **When he wants to create new Robject, select multiple Name input should be empty from the beginning.**

I'm using django-addanother to imitate admin form in my own form. This is how form looks:

```
class RobjectForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Robject  
        fields = '__all__'  
        widgets = {  
            'name': AddAnotherWidgetWrapper(
                forms.SelectMultiple,
                reverse_lazy('add_name', args=['proj_1']),
            ),
        }
```

And CreateNameView:

```
class CreateNameView(CreatePopupMixin, CreateView):
    model = Name
    fields = ['name', "primary"]
    template_name = 'robjects/create_name.html'
```

I will be gratefull for any ideas how to solve my problem.

Comment: can you post the view for the url add_name

Comment: shure I can :-)